Mongol movie about two families exchanging kids
I'm looking for a movie I've watched on TV while ago. It was a story about a brother and sister living in separate locations with their families. The brother is in Tokyo I think and is some kind of a businessman, while his sister lives on the steppes in Mongolia. They are kinda opposite, in a way that the brother enjoys all luxuries we have today, while the sister is living pretty much nomadic and primitive live.
One day they get in contact and decide to swap their kids for a while. The brother sends his son to the steppes, while the sister sends her son to Tokyo for a visit. Everyone experiences different way of life and sees the opposite picture of the table.
The sister is very tough woman and hard working one. She is doing all kinds of jobs around their tiny farm and raises the kids. Of course her husband is also helping a lot, but they are kinda equal with their work on their farm.
I wonder if this is true mongol movie, or might be other Asian movie. But I do remember that it's all around the steppes in Mongolia.

What language was the movie in? And do you have an idea of when it was made?

It was Chinese lang. I think. Not sure what year was made, but I don't think it's before 2000...

Mandarin Chinese I presume (as opposed to Cantonese or some other Chinese dialect)? It might help to know what country you watched it in, since the countries it was distributed to might help narrow it down. Also, do you say it was a Mongol movie because it took place in Mongolia or was there some other reason, like you know it was filmed there?
